# I am Indian living in France, Do i need Mexican tourist visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, tourist-visas, mexico

I am Indian living and working in France. I am planning to visit Mexico for tourism. Do I need a Visa?

Comment: @suman pinnamaneni Do you have permanent residence status in France? https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico

Comment: @Traveller Presumably they do, but it's not required. Any kind of Schengen visa is OK.

Answer (score -2):

You do not require a visa to travel and stay in mexico upto 120 days.

Verified in https://www.traveldoc.aero

Comment: Why downvoted? Is my answer wrong?